# Tensorflow: custom model fails on predict

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I've implemented a Vision Transformer using Tensorflow (2.15) based on several individual custom layers. The model itself is as follows

```
class VisionTransformer(Model):
    def __init__(self, image_size, patch_size, num_channels, n, num_heads, ffn_units, num_classes, output_activation=tf.nn.softmax, epsilon=1e-6, **kwargs):
        super(VisionTransformer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.patch_embedding = PatchEmbedding(image_size, num_channels, patch_size)
        self.encoder = ViEncoder(n, num_heads, self.patch_embedding.hidden_size, epsilon)
        self.ffn = ViFeedForward(ffn_units)
        self.dense = Dense(num_classes, activation=output_activation)

    def call(self, x):
        x = self.patch_embedding(x)
        x = self.encoder(x)
        x = Flatten()(x)
        x = self.ffn(x)
        x = self.dense(x)
        return x

# model testing
vit = VisionTransformer(image_size=200*200, patch_size=25, num_channels=3, n=4, num_heads=8, ffn_units=1024, num_classes=3)
vit(aimages) # 4-d array representing the images
# The output shape is as expected of (num_images, num_classes)

# model fit
vit.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
history = vit.fit(x=aimages, y=y, epochs=1, batch_size=1, verbose=1)

# in-sample prediction
yhat = vit.predict(aimages) # <- fails!
```

Everything works quite fine with exception of predict(). Having a closer look to the error text file it seems that the problem lies in call().

I don't understand why calling call() via instance (model testing) works and calling via predict fails.

Any ideas?

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Edit:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\<user>\<path>\vision_transformer.ipynb Zelle 30 line 6
      3     actuals, preds = np.asarray(actuals), np.asarray(preds)
      4     return np.mean(np.ravel(actuals) == np.ravel(preds))
----> 6 yhat = vit.predict(aimages)
      7 yhat = np.argmax(yhat, axis=1)
      8 yhat = np.asarray(hp['labels'])[yhat]

File c:\Users\<user>\.conda\envs\KI\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
     68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71 finally:
     72     del filtered_tb

File ~\AppData\Local\Temp\__autograph_generated_filev6x13owe.py:15, in outer_factory.<locals>.inner_factory.<locals>.tf__predict_function(iterator)
     13 try:
     14     do_return = True
---> 15     retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
     16 except:
     17     do_return = False

File ~\AppData\Local\Temp\__autograph_generated_filezpeiuaoy.py:20, in outer_factory.<locals>.inner_factory.<locals>.tf__call(self, x)
     18 do_return = False
     19 retval_ = ag__.UndefinedReturnValue()
---> 20 x = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(self).patch_embedding, (ag__.ld(x),), None, fscope)
     21 x = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(self).encoder, (ag__.ld(x),), None, fscope)
     22 x = ag__.converted_call(ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(Flatten), (), None, fscope), (ag__.ld(x),), None, fscope)

File ~\AppData\Local\Temp\__autograph_generated_filew1kb92v3.py:20, in outer_factory.<locals>.inner_factory.<locals>.tf__call(self, x)
     18 do_return = False
     19 retval_ = ag__.UndefinedReturnValue()
---> 20 patches = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(self).get_patches, (ag__.ld(x),), None, fscope)
     21 output = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(self).linear_projection, (ag__.ld(patches),), None, fscope) + ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(self).positional_embedding, (ag__.ld(self).positions,), None, fscope)
     22 try:

File ~\AppData\Local\Temp\__autograph_generated_fileevqxayuv.py:11, in outer_factory.<locals>.inner_factory.<locals>.tf__get_patches(self, x)
      9 retval_ = ag__.UndefinedReturnValue()
     10 patches = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(tf).image.extract_patches, (), dict(images=ag__.ld(x), sizes=[1, ag__.ld(self).patch_size, ag__.ld(self).patch_size, 1], strides=[1, ag__.ld(self).patch_size, ag__.ld(self).patch_size, 1], rates=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='VALID'), fscope)
---> 11 patches = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(tf).reshape, (ag__.ld(patches), (ag__.ld(patches).shape[0], -1, ag__.ld(patches).shape[-1])), None, fscope)
     12 try:
     13     do_return = True

TypeError: in user code:

    File "c:\Users\<user>\.conda\envs\KI\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\engine\training.py", line 2440, in predict_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "c:\Users\<user>\.conda\envs\KI\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\engine\training.py", line 2425, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "c:\Users\<user>\.conda\envs\KI\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\engine\training.py", line 2413, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.predict_step(data)
    File "c:\Users\<user>\.conda\envs\KI\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\engine\training.py", line 2381, in predict_step
        return self(x, training=False)
    File "c:\Users\<user>\.conda\envs\KI\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    File "C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Temp\__autograph_generated_filezpeiuaoy.py", line 20, in tf__call
        x = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(self).patch_embedding, (ag__.ld(x),), None, fscope)
    File "C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Temp\__autograph_generated_filew1kb92v3.py", line 20, in tf__call
        patches = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(self).get_patches, (ag__.ld(x),), None, fscope)
    File "C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Temp\__autograph_generated_fileevqxayuv.py", line 11, in tf__get_patches
        patches = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(tf).reshape, (ag__.ld(patches), (ag__.ld(patches).shape[0], -1, ag__.ld(patches).shape[-1])), None, fscope)

    TypeError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'vision_transformer_2' (type VisionTransformer).
    
    in user code:
    
        File "C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_12696\3472830468.py", line 20, in call  *
            x = self.patch_embedding(x)
        File "c:\Users\<user>\.conda\envs\KI\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler  **
            raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
        File "C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Temp\__autograph_generated_filew1kb92v3.py", line 20, in tf__call
            patches = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(self).get_patches, (ag__.ld(x),), None, fscope)
        File "C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Temp\__autograph_generated_fileevqxayuv.py", line 11, in tf__get_patches
            patches = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(tf).reshape, (ag__.ld(patches), (ag__.ld(patches).shape[0], -1, ag__.ld(patches).shape[-1])), None, fscope)
    
        TypeError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'patch_embedding_3' (type PatchEmbedding).
        
        in user code:
        
            File "C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_12696\2935266798.py", line 39, in call  *
                patches = self.get_patches(x)
            File "C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_12696\2935266798.py", line 25, in get_patches  *
                patches = tf.reshape(patches, (patches.shape[0], -1, patches.shape[-1]))
        
            TypeError: Failed to convert elements of (None, -1, 1875) to Tensor. Consider casting elements to a supported type. See https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/dtypes for supported TF dtypes.
        
        
        Call arguments received by layer 'patch_embedding_3' (type PatchEmbedding):
          • x=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 200, 200, 3), dtype=float32)
    
    
    Call arguments received by layer 'vision_transformer_2' (type VisionTransformer):
      • x=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 200, 200, 3), dtype=float32)
```

Comment: what's the dtype of `aimages`?

Comment: dtype('float32'). Edit: when I set predict(aimages, batch_size=1) everything works